# Amcharts - Export custom dialog for file name

Tags: amcharts

how to add common custom input dialog box for amchart export to give custom file name to downloaded file, irrespective of formats.

I just need to give custom file name on click of any export option before it gets actually downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the file name when the export button has already been clicked. You can however, change the `fileName` in advance.

```
// create your chart
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "export": {
    "fileName": "any_default_filename"
  }
  // ...
});

// HTML
<div>Filename: <input type="text" id="fileName"></div>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

// oninput handler (will set the chart's fileName property)
document.getElementById("fileName").oninput = function(e){
  chart.export.fileName = this.value;
  chart.validateNow();
}
```